# Python/Seaborn: What does the inside horizontal distribution of the data-points means or is it random?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science, scatter-plot

It seems like that inside-distribution of the histogram data points is almost random every time you plot (using Seaborn) - is it for the ease of readability or other meaningful purpose?

I am using Python 3.0 and Seaborn provided dataset called 'tips' for this question.

`import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")`

After I ran my same code below twice I see differences of inside points distribution. Here is the code you can run a couple of times:
`ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, alpha=.55,
                   palette='Set1', jitter=True, linewidth=1 )`

Now, if you look into the plots (if you ran it twice for example) you will notice that the distribution of the points is not the same between 2 plots:

[image: Plot 1 run]
[image: Plot 2 run]

Please explain why points are not distributed identically with 2 separate runs? Also, judging those points on the horizontal scale; is there a reason why (for example) one red point is further left than other red point OR is it simply for readability?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The horizontal distribution is [random but uniform](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/categorical.py#L1152). You can set a seed for the randomness,  `import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)`, such that it would always be the same in case that is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the random seed - now, it make sense. Following 'random but uniform' logic, in this case the distribution between points horizontally has no hidden meaning behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research, I believe that the distribution of data points is [random but uniform](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/categorical.py#L1152) (thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing to the code). Therefore, answering my own questions there is no *hidden* meaning in terms of **distribution** and horizontal range is simply set for visibility that also changes or stays the same based on set/notset seed.

Answer (score 0):

I do think that both displays are identical along the vertical axis (I.e. : both distributions are equal since they represent the same scatter plot of a given dataset). The slight visual differences comes along the position onto the horizontal (categorical days) axis; this one comes from the 'jitter' option (=True) that induces slight random relatively to the vertical axis they are related to (day). The jitter option helps to distinguish scatter plots with the same total_bill value (that should be superimposed if equal) : thus the difference comes from the jitter option set to True, that is used for readability.